# Clang: Getting -Weverything to ignore earlier -Wno- options

Tags: xcode, clang, warnings

## Problem

How can I append -Weverything after some -Wno- options and actually get Clang to enable all warnings?

The background here is that in Xcode, I want to run with -Weverything. However, if I just set -Weverything as "Other Warning Flags", -Weverything ends up after some -Wno options which are added by Xcode.

What should I write in addition to -Weverything to get -Weverything to ignore earlier -Wno options?

Or alternatively, can I configure Xcode to only add my "Other Warning Flags" and not any itself?

## Validation

If you want to test the Clang part of this, take the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  puts("Hello world");
}
```

If you compile it with...

```
clang -Weverything hello.c -o hello
```

... you get a warning about argc and argv being unused as expected.

However, if you *first* disable unused warnings, and *then* enable everything, you won't get the unused warning:

```
clang -Wno-unused-parameter -Weverything hello.c -o hello
```

Comment: Can you disable those `-Wno-XXX` options in Xcode?

Comment: @trojanfoe, I have no idea. But if somebody could tell me how I'd gladly accept that as a solution.

Comment: It's a question of setting various settings from *Yes* to *No*.  I expect that is the only way of fixing this issue.

Comment: That's not a fix, since it will break the next time Apple decides to add more options to Xcode. I'll give you "workaround" though :)

Comment: Changing things in response to changes made by Apple is the name of the game WRT iOS/OSX development, I'm afraid.  This is no different :)